# how to execute a loop in a loop in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

An example of what I need: I have a list of dropdown box and each of the dropdown has 'n' numbers of list of items. I have to verify that all the drop down items are clickable in all the dropdowns box.

Comment: Given that you've created a new question it might be good to remove this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a loop inside a keyword. Then in another the loop, call that keyword

Some thing like this

```
*** Test Cases ***
Run Test
    :FOR    ${i}    IN    ${List}
     \    Keyword A

*** Keywords ***
Keyword A
    # do your loop here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case

     @{list}=  Create List
     ${dbvalues}=  SQL Query
     :FOR  ${variable}  IN  {dbvalues}
     \  ${Value}=  Test Step1  ${variable}
     \  ..........
     \  .........
     \  Append To list  ${list}  ${Value}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.

Comment: This example doesn't show a "loop in a loop", and doesn't contain any explanation of why there is no second loop.